# compare the content of XML

Tags: xml, parsing, xml-parsing, compare

I want to compare the content of two XML, let us suppose the content of this XML is

```
       <Vocab
         description=""
         name="Admin"></Vocab>
        <Vocab
         description=""
         name="Apple"></Vocab>
        <Vocab
         description=""
         name="Notification"></Vocab>
        <Vocab
         description=""
         name="Zebra"></Vocab>
```

Now the content of the second XML is

```
        <Vocab
         description=""
         name="Notification"></Vocab>
        <Vocab
         description=""
         name="Apple"></Vocab>
        <Vocab
         description=""
         name="Admin"></Vocab>
        <Vocab
         description=""
         name="Zebra"></Vocab>
```

Essentially the content's order has changed but the content is still the same but beyond compare show that these are different.
I want a tool to parse the XML in such a way that the result should be finally be compared as per content and show "**NO Difference**". Please any tool for the same/online parser.

Answer (score 0):

You might find that there are options in a sophisticated comparison tool such as DeltaXML to declare that order is insignificant.

But short of that, the general approach should be to transform your two documents to a canonical form using XSLT (e.g. by sorting on @name) and then compare after canonicalising.